# C# - Port Scann with IP Address Ranges

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, port

I have a problem with my code, it works really slow

My Code:

```
private static void PortRangeScan()
{
    Console.Clear();
    var From = FROM.Split('.'); // example (103.218.27.85)
    string From1 = From[0];
    string From2 = From[1];
    string From3 = From[2];
    string From4 = From[3];

    var To = TO.Split('.'); // example (123.218.27.85)
    string To1 = To[0];
    string To2 = To[1];
    string To3 = To[2];
    string To4 = To[3];

    for (int CurrentProxy = int.Parse(From1); CurrentProxy <= int.Parse(To1); CurrentProxy++)
    {
        foreach (int s in Ports)
        {
            TcpClient Scan = new TcpClient();
            try
            {
                // If there is no exception then the Port is open
                Scan.Connect($"{CurrentProxy}.{From2}.{From3}.{From4}", s);
                Console.WriteLine($"[{CurrentProxy}.{From2}.{From3}.{From4}] | [{s}] | OPEN", Color.Green);
            }
            catch
            {
                // If there is an excpetion then it means the Port is closed
                Console.WriteLine($"[{CurrentProxy}.{From2}.{From3}.{From4}] | [{s}] | CLOSED", Color.Red);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code works really slow, if the port is closed, it can take up to 10 seconds until it checks the next port.

I wanted to add a Parallel.For loop or multi-threading but I am not sure how I can do it with this code.
so what do I need:

how can I make this code much faster or how can I add multi-threading

Answer (score 0):

You could use the System.Net.Network Information namespace. Specifically the IPGlobal properties class. It can be used to return a full list of the currently used ports.

Sorry for the formatting. I am on mobile, but here is an example.

```
var ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties(); 
var tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
foreach (var tcpi in tcpConnInfoArray)
{
  Console.Write($"Port {tcpi.LocalEndPoint.Port} is in use.");
}
```